# How do I get my method visible in the Swagger UI?

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a Web API using Swagger and a minimal method:

```
app.Map("Hello/{*rest}", (HttpRequest request, string rest) => $"Hello, World! Request: {request.Method} -> {rest}").WithName("Hello");
```

But the Swagger UI is not showing this method in the list of methods and it is not part of the Swagger JSON it creates. I assume because that's because this method has no HTTP method like GET, POST or whatever associated to it. And I don't want to limit it to one HTTP method. This minimal function must accept them all.
Does this mean that I can't include it into my Swagger UI and API?
This method is part of a simple gateway project I'm working on. It's no problem if it doesn't show up in Swagger. It's just annoying. :)

Comment: look at this [article](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/documenting-additional-api-endpoints-in-swagger-in-asp-net-core-59da9c84e4ba)

Comment: @CodingMytra Basically, that's way too complex to use. I know what it does, as it just adds the API with all it's parameters to the Swagger UI but it makes the code too tricky to maintain as any change to my API would require a change in this filter. That's what I want to avoid!

Comment: David Fowler has a gist on supporting OpenAPI/Swagger with minimal APIs: https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/ff1addd02d239d2d26f4648a06158727#openapi

You do not need a custom document filter.

Comment: @nullforce It seems using .MapMethod() solves what I'm trying here, but with some restrictions. Swagger requires a http method to be part of the description and does not support the "CONNECT" method, while "TRACE" and "HEAD" have some additional challenges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MapMethods`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutebuilderextensions.mapmethods) which allows to pass in all the HTTP methods you want to support.

Below example specifies GET and POST which both appear in Swagger.

```
app.MapMethods(
    "Hello/{*rest}",
    new[] { "GET", "POST" }, 
    (HttpRequest request, string rest) => $"Hello, World! Request: {request.Method} -> {rest}").WithName("Hello");
```

Comment: Looks good. It works for all methods except "CONNECT". Which is not a big problem. The "HEAD" method gives no content back and the "TRACE" method results in the exception *TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': 'TRACE' HTTP method is unsupported.*
Fortunately, these methods will not be used. Just tested with them.

Comment: @WimtenBrink Looks like Swagger is constrained to a [fixed set](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/c70947f4ccc80bca528ff1573c0f2462f3e7db8f/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/SwaggerGenerator/SwaggerGenerator.cs#L608) of HTTP methods :/